# Browser url is getting replaced by the hash value on page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have url like

`localhost:8000/mywebsitedomain.com/#/home`

when ever I am changing the tab the url is also changing to

`localhost:8000/mywebsitedomain.com/#/about`

But when ever I am refreshing the page ,that time URL is changing to `localhost:8000/home` - website domain is getting replaced by the hash value. I am using `angularJs1.4`  `ng-router`.

Comment: the #/home etc is appended due to angular routing...

Comment: you should get rid of the slash after the hash. this would prevent the mistake. could you access you tabs by #home and #about?

Comment: This might be due to server side routing? If you don't have control over serverside you can enable HTML5 mode.

Comment: Seems you have conflicting routing configs on server and in angular. Show both. Nobody can guess what you have set up. See [mcve]

Comment: But that #/home is appending automatically by the browser.